# Tower of Hanoi with 4 Towers

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

In the Tower of Hanoi game with $4$ towers, let ${W_n}$ denote the minimum number of moves needed to transfer $n$ disks from one tower to another tower. Each disk may be transferred from one tower to another, but no larger disk may be placed on top of a smaller one at any point of time.

Show that, for all $n\ge0$, $$W_{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}} \le 2^n \cdot (n-1) + 1$$

How do I prove the above inequality? Is it solving for the recurrence relation

${W_n} \le 2 \cdot W_{n-k} + 2^k - 1$, for $0 \le k \le n$ ?

Comment: It is not quite clear to me what is the question. Are you asking whether your recurrence relation is true? It is. Or are you asking whether it does lead to the estimate you need to show? It does.

Comment: Yes, I need to show how the recurrence relation leads to the estimate above, but have no idea how to go about starting it. I've assumed _Wn_ to take on the form of some solutions but the _k_ remains in the equation, any idea how to start?

Comment: $n(n+1)\over2$ _screams for_ splitting it like $1+2+\ldots+n$. Assume you know it to be true for $W_{(n-1)n\over2}$, then add $n$.